# What is the output of: printf("%d\n",scanf("%d",&i))?

Tags: c, io, return, printf, scanf

What is the output of this code if I input **25** to `scanf()`? I run this program, the output is **1** but I don't understand why? Can anyone explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int i;
  printf("%d\n",scanf("%d",&i));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is time to read the man page for [`scanf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-scanf-l-wscanf-wscanf-l?view=vs-2019) to find out about its return value: the number of fields successfully converted and assigned. It's *essential* to check this value when using the `scanf` function family.

Comment: Why did you write code that you don't understand what it does?

Comment: @Lundin: What makes you think they wrote the code?

Comment: Why would _anybody_ write code like this, except to confuse??

Comment: As part of an exercise, I would imagine, @KevinBoone, or perhaps as an experiment.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf()` returns the number of arguments successfully assigned. In your case, `scanf` only has one directive which has a respective argument to be assigned, so it returns `1` if the input conversion was done successfully.

`1` is given now as argument to `printf`, which prints `1` into the output.

---

With the premise that the `scanf()` conversion was successfully,

```
printf("%d\n", scanf("%d",&i));
```

is basically equivalent to

```
printf("%d\n", 1);
```

---

Going straight forward

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
printf("%d\n", scanf("%d %d", &i, &j));
```

with the input of

```
25(enter)
50(enter)
```

and both conversions done successfully, would gave you the output `2` and

```
printf("%d\n", scanf("%d %d", &i, &j));
```

would basically be equivalent to

```
printf("%d\n", 2);
```

---

Side Note:

The return value of `scanf()` should *always* be checked by the algorithm but it is more an objective to the program to see if an input failure occurred than to diagnose it directly to the user.

Answer (score 1):

These functions (scanf family) return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned.

So in this case it can return `1` if the scan was successful or `0` if not. If there is an error in the input stream it can also return `EOF`

Answer (score 0):

***Scanf*** is a basic function in C language.Since every function return a type of value or null,Scanf function ***returns numbers of inputs scanned successfully***.

For Example: Scanf("%d%d") scans for 2 inputs, so it returns value 2.
Scanf("%f%d%d%d") scans for 4 inputs, so it returns value 4.

&variable_name is used to store the scanned value in the variable by using address-of operator.For scanning string, &-address-of operator can be neglible.
Example scanf("%s",variable)

***Printf*** is a function which ***returns number of characters printed***.It can be used with format specifer like %d,%f etc.

In the above program

```
printf("%d\n",scanf("%d",&i));
```

Scanf is first executed by scanning one integer input as %d is specified and stored in the variable of type int. ***Scanf returns value 1*** since it is scanning only one input.
Printf function prints the value 1.Printing value does not depend upon input value.It depends only on number of inputs , scanf is scanned successfully.

Answer (score -2):

you are outputting the scanf function which returns the variable numbers not the value in i.